# Using shift_level_max() function in time series - R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, decomposition

When I use [`shift_level_max()`](https://otexts.com/fpp3/other-features.html) to find the largest mean shift between two consecutive sliding windows of the time series.

```
data("AirPassengers")
air.ts <- AirPassengers

library(feasts)
shift_level_max(air.ts)
```

The output is following:

```
  shift_level_max shift_level_index 
             62.6             127.0
```

could you tell me what **shift_level_index**  (127) means? Or which period is it in the data?

Comment: What does the tag stl, C++ standard library, have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

From the help file for `feasts::shift_level_max()`:

> Value:
> A vector of 2 values: the size of the shift, and the time index of the shift.

So the second value shows that the largest shift in level occurs at the 127th observation of the data set.